# Validate textbox float input with either . or ,

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I try to allow decimal input only in textbox using WPF c#, but allowing a single occurence of either "," or "."

I managed to validate float input in textbox using "." with

```
void NumericTextBoxInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$");

    if (regex.IsMatch(e.Text) && !(e.Text == "." && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(e.Text)))
           e.Handled = false;
    else
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

now I try to do the same, including a "," as decimal marker. the following regex is OK, but I don't manage to allow only one "." or one "," and then get the both decimal marker disabled.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:(\.|\,)[0-9]*)?$");
```

Do someone know how to allow only one occurence of "," or "."?

Comment: Sounds to me like the completely wrong approach (maybe even an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). Using `float.TryParse` together with the correct culture would be the way I would go.

Comment: I understand, but I want the textbox to allow user to input either a dot or a comma as decimal marker, and avoid typo like writing 2 decimal markers instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally managed using:

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{

    string input = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;

    string pattern = "^[0-9]+[.|,]?([0-9]+)?$";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(input);

}
```

seems my initial regex was not the proper one.
So now, as intended, I can input only digits, and either a , or a . but only once.
Hope this will be useful to someone.

For info, I process the , or . later in the code:

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(myValue, @"(,)"))
        { Double.TryParse(myValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out myValued); }
        else { Double.TryParse(myValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myValued); }
```